# Rails 5 Rspec Trait with associates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have some doubt with rails 5.2.8 and rspec

To create the object and trait with array associated the rspec code is

```
let!(:transfer)             { Transfer.last }
let!(:transfer_method_type) { create(:transfer_method_type, :with_transfer_methods, transfer: transfer) }
```

And the factory as:

```
FactoryBot.define do 
  factory :transfer_method_type, class: "TransferMethodType" do
    association :transfer_methods, transfer

    transfer_method_type_name   { 'Other' }

    trait :with_transfer_methods do
        association :transfer,
        transfer_methods { 
            [
              create(:transfer_method, transfer: transfer),
              create(:transfer_method, transfer: transfer, option: 'Other 2')
            ]
        }
      end
  end
end
```

But have an error testing it

> Transfer Method Type Tests Show, Update, Delete Deletes a Transfer Method Type
>
> Failure/Error: let!(:transfer_method_type) { create(:transfer_method_type, :with_transfer_methods, transfer: transfer) }
>
> ArgumentError:
>
> Trait not registered: transfer

Not sure how to fix it

Comment: I think the variable `transfer` is not available in the transfer_method_type factory.

Answer (score 0):

The code `association :transfer_methods, transfer` is basically short for:

```
transfer_methods { [ create :transfer_method, transfer ] }
```

Ie. the `transfer` argument is being seen as the trait of the `transfer_method` factory. Unsurprisingly, there's no trait matching the `Transfer` object you're passing in as the `transfer` attribute.